# Error in code .xslt for .xml generated by excel

Tags: xslt, apache-camel

I'm trying take datas in file xml generated by excel... I removed some tags and my xml looks like this:

```
<Table>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ISSN</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Título</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Estrato</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1084-6654</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ACM Journal of Experimental Algorithmics</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B4</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">1550-4832</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ACM Journal on Emerging Technologies in Computing Systems</Data></Cell>
        <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">B2</Data></Cell>
    </Row>
</Table>
```

and my code xslt is this:

```
` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Table">
            <xsl:for-each select="Row">
                <xsl:for-each select="Cell">
                    <xsl:for-each select="Data">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Data[last()]"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I will to compile with apache camel, it doesnt compile.

Erro: `ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DESKTOP-L78T6HF-52943-1475869300542-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-DESKTOP-L78T6HF-52943-1475869300542-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,32]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114#AttributePrefixUnbound?Data&ss:Type&ss`

Comment: _"It doesn't compile"_ is insufficient description.  Please explain exactly what you are seeing, and copy/paste any error messages into your post (use the [edit] facility).

Comment: Hi Jim, ok, thanks. I updated

Comment: I am quite sure that Excel does **not** generate a file like the one shown here. When you "*removed some tags*", you have apparently removed more than warranted - resulting in a file that's not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT. I would suggest you learn how to transform the original file. XSLT is perfectly capable of handling namespaces, there is no need to remove them beforehand - esp.when you don't know how.

Comment: Hi Michael! I had sucess, I used complete XML. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your input has attributes named `ss:Type` -  but the `ss` prefix is not bound to a *namespace*. That is not allowed in XML.

Other than that, your XSLT styleheet makes very little sense to me - but that's another issue, and we'd have to see your expected output to tackle that.